# Looping through Python Dict and Normalising

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, normalization

I have multiple dict in a list and I want loop through each dict and flatten the file. When I run this code its giving me the 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable error. And the custom fields in the below json will be having many other fields as well

```
import asana
import json
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate


client = asana.Client.access_token('Access_token')

portfolio_items = client.portfolios.get_items_for_portfolio('Portfolio_id',
                                                            opt_fields = ['gid'],
                                                            opt_pretty=True
                                                           )
Project_list = pd.DataFrame(portfolio_items)


project_details = []

for (index, row_data) in Project_list.iterrows():
    project_object=client.projects.get_project(project_gid=row_data["gid"],
                                               opt_fields = [
                                                                'gid','name','start_on','archived','completed',
                                                                'completed_at','created_at','current_status.color','current_status.created_at',
                                                                'current_status.modified_at','custom_fields.name','custom_fields.display_value'
                                                            ],opt_pretty= True
                                              )
    project_details.append(project_object)

Flatten_file = pd.DataFrame()
if project_details is not None:
    for project in project_details:
        flatten_json_file1 = pd.json_normalize(project,record_path =['custom_fields'],
                                           meta=['gid', 'name','start_on','archived','completed','completed_at','created_at', ['current_status', 'Color'],['current_status', 'created_at'],['current_status', 'modified_at']],
                                           errors='ignore',
                                           meta_prefix='meta-',
                                           record_prefix='custom-'
                                          )
        Flatten_file.append(flatten_json_file1)
print(Flatten_file)
```

Project_details list will be consisting of info like this

```
[
   {
      "gid": "324673284",
      "archived": false,
      "completed": false,
      "completed_at": null,
      "created_at": "2022-10-25T18:20:01.358Z",
      "current_status": null,
      "custom_fields": [
         {
            "gid": "279970056320993",
            "name": "Priority",
            "display_value": null
         },
         {
            "gid": "1202467628629378",
            "name": "Size ( PXT-BI )",
            "display_value": "Large"
         },

      ],
      "name": "Hawkeye Anecdote Escalation Model",
      "start_on": null
   },
   {
      "gid": "3878432832",
      "archived": false,
      "completed": false,
      "completed_at": null,
      "created_at": "2022-12-13T01:24:45.658Z",
      "current_status": null,
      "custom_fields": [

         {
            "gid": "1202467628629378",
            "name": "Size ( PXT-BI )",
            "display_value": "Small"
         },
         {
            "gid": "1202475692803938",
            "name": "Project Type ( PXT-BI )",
            "display_value": null
         },
         {
            "gid": "1202537017669433",
            "name": "Tracks ( PXT-BI )",
            "display_value": "Strategic Programs"
         },
         {
            "gid": "1202467628625109",
            "name": "Scrum Stage ( PXT-BI )",
            "display_value": "In Progress"
         }
      ],
      "name": "Create Data Connection For New Conversions Dashboard",
      "start_on": null
   }
]
```

And My desired Output should be looking like

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preparing the data:

```
Project_details = *the array above you inserted*
Project_details
```

It returns your array of dicts. Then you use list comprehension:

```
dataset = [
    [proj['gid'], proj['archived'], proj['completed'], proj['created_at'], custom_field['name'], custom_field['display_value']]
        for proj in Project_details
            for custom_field in proj['custom_fields']]
dataset
```

Then you built 1 row with the goal data. Let's format dataframe:

```
col = ['Gid', 'Archived', 'Completed', 'created_at', 'Custom Fields_key', 'Value']
df = pd.DataFrame(data = dataset, columns = col)
df
```

The output showed by jupyter:
[image: DataFrame result]